# list of scraped elements showing output in different format

Tags: python-3.x, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape weather report data of a particular region using BeautifulSoup4 in Python.
Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
import sys


url = 'https://www.accuweather.com/en/in/guwahati/186893/weather-forecast/186893'
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=agent)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml') #= bs4 element
#print(soup.prettify())


#alldata is a tag of bs4 element
alldata = soup.find_all(class_='day-panel')


#This will give us all the required data we just need to arrange it nicely
datas = []
for h in alldata:
    datas.append(h.text.strip())

print(datas)
print(datas[0])
```

First print statement showing output as:

```
['Current Weather\n\t\n\n\t\t11:55 PM\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t22°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tC\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t20°\n\t\n\n\t\tPartly cloudy', 'Today\n\t\n\n\t\t3/31\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t34°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tHi\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t36°\n\t\n\n\t\tVery warm with hazy sunshine', 'Tonight\n\t\n\n\t\t3/31\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t16°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tLo\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t16°\n\t\n\n\t\tPatchy clouds', 'Tomorrow\n\t\n\n\t\t4/1\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t36°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t/ 16°\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\tHot with hazy sunshine']
```

I want only the text, not in a list.
Second print statement showing output as:

```
Current Weather


        11:56 PM




            22°


                C



        RealFeel®
        20°


        Mostly clear
```

Expected output:

```
'Current Weather\n\t\n\n\t\t11:55 PM\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t22°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tC\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t20°\n\t\n\n\t\tPartly cloudy'
```

How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is printing like that is that Python is making newlines and tabs for each `\n` and `\t` in the data. To ignore these escape characters when printing, use the Python `repr` function.

Like this:

```
print(repr(datas[0]))
```

The output:

```
'Current Weather\n\t\n\n\t\t12:28 AM\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t71°\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\tF\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\tRealFeel®\n\t\t69°\n\t\n\n\t\tMostly clear'
```